# How to create PLSQL Function & Error in sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi experts i need to implement an  PL/SQL function HIGHTRIP(LICENSENUM) that finds the  the longest trip performed by a driver identified by a driving license number (LNUM attribute in table DRIVER and parameter LICENSENUM parameter in the function). I need to displays about the drivers that do not perform any trip also.

This is what i have done so far.

```
SELECT DRIVER.LNUM AS LICENSE_NO,
COUNT(TRIP.TNUM) AS TOTAL_NO_TRIPS
FROM DRIVER
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRIP
ON DRIVER.LNUM = TRIP.LNUM
INNER JOIN TRIPLEG
ON TRIP.TNUM = TRIPLEG.TNUM
GROUP BY DRIVER.LNUM
ORDER BY DRIVER.LNUM
```

However the statement above does not displays abt drivers who has not made any trips.

Not sure how to convert the statement into a function that satisfy the criteria above.

Comment: :You have asked mutiple questions and that is confusing me  `first :`you need a function `HIGHTRIP(LICENSENUM)`,that take license number as input and based on that ,you want to retrieve `lenght`,`second`:you need a function to retireve length of all the drivers.`Third`:you want to display drivers that do not perform any trip.Now what functionality you want to implement,and please post the table structure with some data ,that will help us .

Comment: @GauravSoni I have edited the question. My issue is only one. i Need to create a function thats does above.

Comment: so with your final set of edits, why do you need a function as opposed to that SQL itself ? drop the join to TRIPLEG (you're not using it) and it will give you drivers that have no trips (or change it to left outer join..but then the count as-is would report the number of trip legs)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suggest you split your requirement, starting with the simplest part and building up instead of trying to write the whole query first. Your query returns the number of lines in the `TRIPLEG` table for a given driver, which doesn't seem to answer your requirement. Let me also suggest that you take a look at the [PL/SQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm), especially the [CREATE FUNCTION syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/function.htm#i34368) and some [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#CIHBEGEG).

For example, I would have broken down your problem in the following subtasks:

1. Length of trips for one driver. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I were to list all trips with their associated length, this would be:

   ```
   SELECT t.tnum, COUNT(*) length
     FROM trip t
     JOIN tripleg tl ON t.tnum = tl.tnum
    WHERE t.lnum = :LNUM
    GROUP BY t.tnum
   ```
2. Select the longest of these trips:

   ```
   SELECT tnum
     FROM (SELECT t.tnum, COUNT(*) length
              FROM trip t
              JOIN tripleg tl ON t.tnum = tl.tnum
             WHERE t.lnum = :LNUM
             GROUP BY t.tnum
             ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
      WHERE rownum = 1
   ```
3. Write a function that returns this result:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hightrip (p_lnum trip.lnum%type) 
      RETURN trip.tnum%type IS
      l_result trip.tnum%type;
   BEGIN
      SELECT tnum
        INTO l_result
        FROM (SELECT t.tnum, COUNT(*) length
                 FROM trip t
                 JOIN tripleg tl ON t.tnum = tl.tnum
                WHERE t.lnum = p_lnum
                GROUP BY t.tnum
                ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
         WHERE rownum = 1;
      RETURN l_result;
   END hightrip ;
   ```
4. Use this function on your SELECT:

   ```
   SELECT d.*, hightrip(d.lnum)
     FROM driver d;
   ```

The `HIGHTRIP` function will produce a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception when called from `PL/SQL` for a driver without trips. However, such an exception is treated as `NULL` from SQL, so you can use the above query as is.

Comment: Thanks alot. I am able to understand and learn clearly. While testing your solution 2. I realise rownum, but it is not declared anywhere. What is it and what is it for ?

Comment: I would like to know how differenciate the duplicates. Cause according to my records i have 3 trips that 5 legs each. But tyour statement is giving only the the first trip that has the 5 legs.

Comment: Thanks a million. It works wonderful. But i would like to learn abt the queries i posted earlier. Its for learning. I don't want to copy blindly. Would appericate if you can explain about my queries. Once again. Thank You SO MUCH.

Comment: `ROWNUM` is a [pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255) used to do TOP-N query in Oracle (find the first N rows of a result set). In the function we select the first row that has the most legs that Oracle finds. If there are duplicates the choice is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

> "However the statement above does not displays abt drivers who has not
>   made any trips."

Driver's without any trips won't have any records in TRIPLEG.  Therefore your INNER JOIN on that table will override the OUTER JOIN between DRIVER and TRIP, and thus filter out the drivers who stayed at home.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
SELECT DRIVER.LNUM AS LICENSE_NO,
       TRIPS.TOTAL_NO_TRIPS
FROM DRIVER
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT TRIP.LNUM,
                         COUNT(TRIP.TNUM)  AS TOTAL_NO_TRIPS
                  FROM TRIP
                       INNER JOIN TRIPLEG
                       ON TRIP.TNUM = TRIPLEG.TNUM
                       GROUP BY TRIP.LNUM ) TRIPS
    ON DRIVER.LNUM = TRIPS.LNUM
ORDER BY DRIVER.LNUM 
/
```

What you also want is to learn how to use *lower case* in your code.  Programs written entirely in upper case went out with COBOL, because they are too hard to read.